# What does "aspect model" refer to in machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, recommender-system

Hopefully this is the right place to ask my question. 
I am reading this paper about cold-start recommendations: http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1352837

the expression "aspect model" is used a lot : in the abstract (sentence before last sentence), and at the beginning of section2.

Is anyone able to shed some light here ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

So ! I did so more research and found the signification of "aspect model", in the paper of the  author Mr Hoffman who coined the expression in this paper : http://cs.brown.edu/~th/papers/Hofmann-SIGIR99.pdf

The definition is at the top of page 2 (section 2). 
Enjoy :)

Comment: Link is now a 404. New link: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1301.6705.pdf (Probabilistic Latent Semantic Analysis)